# Возможно ли удалить комиты которые уже есть в git?

Tags: git, github, gitlab, git-commit, git-push

Прочитал много материала, делала с помощью rebase, но получается с помощью reabase комиты не удаляются, а как бы объединяются и старые тоже остаются. [image: введите сюда описание изображения] у меня есть комиты, с new по new7 могу ли я из удалённого репозитория удалить комиты с new по new4? или это не возможно?

Comment: можно с помошью rebase объеденить их, а потом сделать force push, из истории они пропадут, но по хешу их на github можно будет найти

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Коммиты удаляются автоматически после того, как ни одна ветка не будет его содержать. Ветку можно удалить или перенести на другую цепочку коммитов.

Хоть с локальным, хоть с удалённым репозиторием это работает одинаково.

С удалённым репозиторием есть сложность в том, что кто-то из команды мог стянуть эти изменения себе, и продолжить разработку основываясь на них. После того, как он сделает push, коммит вернётся обратно.

Если с репозиторием работает ограниченное количество людей, то можно их оповестить.

Для публичных репозиториев изменение истории считается крайне нежелательным именно потому, что старую версию истории у себя уже имеют много неизвестных вам людей.